# Unable to click on checkbox using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#, specflow, ie

I am passing in the checkbox ID, grabbing the element and then if the checkbox is not checked I want to check it. It wouldn't check the box though, so I was debugging and then it worked when I added a second one in, so I added 2 to make it work and cleaned up some clutter I had created with commented code and such, then I ran it again and it didn't check the checkbox on either click. The funny thing is that I am getting focus on the checkbox.

Could this be an issue when there are certain security measures in place for the code?  Is there a workaround for this?

Not sure if it matters but I am using XUnit for the testing framework.

```
[Then(@"I check the '(.*)' checkbox")]
public void ThenICheckTheCheckbox(string checkBoxId)
{
    var checkBox = Ie.FindElementById(checkBoxId);
    var isChecked = checkBox.Selected;

    if (!isChecked)
    {
        checkBox.Click(); 
        checkBox.Click();
        isChecked = checkBox.Selected;

    }
    Assert.True(isChecked, $"the checkbox with id of: {checkBoxId}, is not checked");

}
```

The HTML for the checkbox is this

```
<input class="check-box" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Is Active field is required." 
    id="IsActive" name="IsActive" type="checkbox" value="true">
```

Comment: wouldn't let me add a new tag [tag:xunit]

Comment: I'd recommend rolling back to the untidy, working version then go from there.

Comment: @Bookeater my current solution has me executing a client side script against the page to check the checkbox

Comment: Can you show me the checkbox Id you are using to find the element

Comment: pretty sure it is the ID in the HTML of the Element -->  `IsActive` @user1519137  it has been over a year, I would have to find this code again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than accessing the element by Id try doing it with xpath. I can see the there is an  tag attached to this element. So you could make use of that.So for example if your checkbox is setup like this:

```
<div id = "divContainer">
<input class="check-box" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Is Active 
 field is required." 
id="IsActive" name="IsActive" type="checkbox" value="true">
 </div>
```

Then you can use something like this:

```
 bool selected 
 =driver.findElemeny(By.xpath(.//[@id='divContainer']/input)).isSelected();
```

And then you can make use of the selected variable to click or unclick the checkbox. If you could provide me with the full page's code then I will be able to write the full xpath for you